EF Core Migration doesnt work any more after upgrading JsonWebTokens from 7.6.0. to 8.x
When upgrading my nugets from 7.6.0 to 8.x, the EF Core migration command fails.
It works, when I dont upgrade.
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.6.0" />

EF Command:
dotnet ef migrations add Test
(but also fails on e.g. dotnet ef migrations has-pending-model-changes)
DbContext:
public class GenesisDbContext : DbContext
{
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public GenesisDbContext(DbContextOptions<GenesisDbContext> dbContextOptions, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    }

// Just a few DbSets and seeding here

When I run with 7.6.0 the command
dotnet ef migrations has-pending-model-changes

I get:

No changes have been made to the model since the last migration.

When I upgrade to 8.1.0 I Get:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[SMS.Server.Genesis.Data.GenesisDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'KommuneAktiv.SMS.Server.Genesis.Data.GenesisDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Not much I could try here, just "dont update" :)
